# Use a Date from a Cell Reference as Part of the Array Table location in a VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an inventory analysis that I run for my workplace, and part of the analysis compares the inventory value for a given item for the current reporting week to the inventory value of the item for the previous reporting week, and finds the difference to determine the change in value.

I'm trying to use an INDIRECT function in my VLOOKUP formula to plug in the formated Year, Month, and Date that form part of the address for the VLOOKUP's table array, but I keep getting a "#REF" error when I use this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A8,INDIRECT("'F:\Purchasing\PDM\Reporting\Inventory Snapshot\" & (C3,"YYYY") & "\" & TEXT(C3,"MM") & " - " & TEXT(C3,"MMMM") & "\" & TEXT(C3,"MM-DD-YYYY") & "\[Inv Snapshot - " & TEXT(C3,"MM-DD-YYYY") & ".xlsx]Pivot 3'!$A:$E"),3,FALSE)
```

I can't catch what I'm doing wrong here; could anyone help me figure out where my bug might be?